# Are smooth solutions to a PDE dense in the space of $L^2$ solutions to the PDE?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde

Let's say I have a linear differential operator $P$ with smooth coefficients between bundles $E$ and $F$ over a smooth compact manifold $X$ with smooth boundary. Let's consider $P$ as an operator between the Sobolev spaces $P\colon L^2(X;E)\to L^2_{-m}(X;F)$, giving us a subspace $\ker P\subseteq L^2(X;E)$. Is $\ker P\cap C^\infty(X;E)$ dense in $\ker P$?

For example, we can consider $d\colon L^2(B^n;\bigwedge^*T^*B^n)\to L^2_{-1}(B^n;\bigwedge^*T^*B^n)$, in which case the question asks whether smooth closed forms on a ball are $L^2$-dense in $L^2$ closed forms on the ball.

I suspect that the answer to the question is yes, at least with appropriate assumptions, but if you know of an analysis textbook that handles something like this situation, I'd appreciate a reference.

Comment: I would be very surprised if this would hold generally. If the PDE is elliptic, however, then it is trivial, because everything in the kernel is smooth.

Comment: Consider the $0$-th order linear operator $P: f \mapsto f-w$, where $w$ is an arbitrary section. Then $\ker P = \mathbb{R}w$, so if $w$ is not smooth, then what you want is false.

Comment: @OtisChodosh: The question does specify "smooth coefficients", though.

Comment: In addition, $f\mapsto f-w$ doesn't map zero to zero, and so is not a linear operator in the usual sense. To clarify, I'm thinking about differential operators as on Wikipedia: $P(x,D)=\sum_{|\alpha|\le m}a_\alpha(x) D^\alpha$, where the $a_\alpha$ are smooth.

Comment: @MatthiasLudewig, some evidence in favor is that the claim holds for constant coefficient operators in $\mathbb R^n$, because differentiation commutes with convolution. Thus, if $f$ is in the kernel of a constant coefficient differential operator, if we approximate $f$ with smooth functions via convolution with a compactly supported smooth function, those approximations will also be in the kernel of the operator.

Comment: Whoops, sorry I take back my comment.

Comment: I talked to a friend who told me that the claim is false. I don't want to take credit by posting her answer as mine, but I'll leave the counterexample here in case someone comes across this question later: The operator is $u\mapsto(x\partial_x-1.5)u$, and she says that it has a two-dimensional space of solutions that are not smooth.

Comment: @MatthiasLudewig I don't think this is quite correct, because no boundary conditions have been specified. For instance, if $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth, bounded domain, it is possible to construct harmonic functions $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ that are not smooth. For elliptic regularity to apply, one needs $\left. u \right|_{\partial\Omega}$ to be smooth (which is of course satisfied for the DIrichlet problem).

Comment: @GrahamCox: Elliptic regularity is a local question, so nothing over the boundary is needed. Of course, if you want smoothness *up to the boundary*, then you will need properties of the boundary. But for interior smoothness, nothing like this is needed. In particular, there are no harmonic functions on an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which are not smooth.

Comment: @MatthiasLudewig Since $X$ is compact, I interpreted "smooth" as  "smooth up to the boundary"; of course what you said about interior regularity is correct. Concerning the harmonic function example, I should have said there exist harmonic functions that are not smooth _up to the boundary_, meaning they are elements of $C^\infty(\Omega) \setminus C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$.

Comment: @GrahamCox: Thank you for the clarification. I may have overread that $X$ may have a boundary in ops original post.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any reason this will hold for an arbitrary differential operator with smooth coefficients. If the operator has additional structure (such as ellipticity) then one can say something meaningful.

As pointed out in the comments above, the result follows easily from elliptic regularity if either: 1) $X$ is closed (has no boundary); or 2) by $\ker P$ you really mean "sections that satisfy $Pu = 0$ plus an appropriate boundary condition."

A more interesting question is when $X$ has a boundary (as in the original question) and no boundary conditions are imposed. Then $\ker P$ is infinite-dimensional and contains sections that are not smooth all the way up to the boundary. However, one can still give an affirmative answer to this problem if $P$ is elliptic and the Dirichlet realizations of $P$ and $P^*$ both have trivial kernel.

The key ingredients are: 1) elliptic regularity; 2) unique solvability of the Dirichlet problem; and 3) continuous dependence of the solution on the boundary data. As an illustration, I'll describe the case of the Laplacian on a smooth, bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Suppose $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ solves $\Delta u = 0$ in a weak (distributional) sense. Then $f := \left.u\right|_{\partial\Omega}$ is contained in $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$, so there exists a sequence $\{f_j\}$ in $C^\infty(\partial\Omega)$ such that $\|f - f_j\|_{H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)} \to 0$. For each $j$ the Dirichlet problem $$\Delta u_j = 0, \quad \left.u_j\right|_{\partial\Omega} = f_j$$ has a unique solution. Since $f_j$ is smooth, elliptic regularity implies $u_j \in C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$. Moreover, one has the estimate $$\|u_j\|_{H^1(\Omega)} \leq C \|f_j\|_{H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)}$$ where $C$ does not depend on $j$, so $u_j \to u$ in $H^1(\Omega)$. Therefore, the set of smooth (up to the boundary) harmonic functions is $H^1$-dense in the set of weakly harmonic functions.